# Reference data for a SDP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

So I've recently been trying to understand semidefinite programs (and hopefully write a program to solve them later on), but one issue I've had is I don't have any data I can use to test either anything I'd write, or even anything I could run through cvx or pre made algorithms to help me understand it better.

I apologize if this is a bit of a silly question but I've been looking into it on my own and thus don't have a professor who gives us data in homeworks, many examples just use random data, and the only data set I've been able to find is at [the end of this](http://sdpa.sourceforge.net/whatissdp.pdf) but it's not very big and is just one dataset. I'm also concerned to try to make my own because I'm both not sure how and since I'm still learning this afraid I'll make it improperly.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Hans Mittelmann has a collection of benchmarks where various SDP problems were solved by different solvers.  You can download the problem data:

http://plato.asu.edu/bench.html

SDPLIB is a collection of SDP instances:

http://euler.nmt.edu/~brian/sdplib/